# How change Prestashop Order status with php in validate order

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

How change **Prestashop** Order status with **php** in validate order
i'm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$history = new OrderHistory();
$history->id_order = (int)$order->id;
$history->changeIdOrderState(27, (int)($order->id));
```